# Y-Axis units on FFT graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, computer-science, power-series, fourier-series

A 50Hz sinusoid wave with a voltage range of +/-20V is sampled at 512Hz for 1 second. No bias or phase shift are present. The signal is run through an FFT. The result is one spike at 50Hz on the frequency domain with power of $226.274$.

My question is, how do we get from an amplitude of +/-20V on the voltage-time graph to an amplitude of $226.274$ on the FFT graph. I know the formula $|F(w)|^2=(x^2+y^2)/N$ applies in this situation, but what are the variables? Please keep answers simple, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: it depends of what you are measuring. most time it's the energy $I \times U$ so they are watts, but you can also FFT the voltage or the intensity or the derivative of intensity (there is also the impedance $U/I$ which is useful to Fourier transform), it depends the spectrum analyser you are using. it's physics ! ask physicians !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got that power (amplitude?) value. If I do the same in Matlab/Octave then I get exactly the expected amplitude of $NA/2=5120$, where $N=512$ is the FFT length and $A=20$ is the amplitude of the signal:

```
n=0:511;
x=20*sin(2*pi*50/512*n);
X=fft(x);
max(abs(X))

ans =  5120.0
```

Note that for a real-valued sinusoidal signal (with a frequency that lies exactly on the FFT grid), you always get two peaks, each with amplitude $NA/2$. This is a result of the following property of the DFT for real-valued signals:

$$X[k]=X^*[N-k]$$

Comment: in matlab: $fft(x)[k] = \sum_{n=1}^N x[n] e^{-2i \pi (n-1) (k-1) / N}$, and $ifft(X)[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N X[k] e^{-2i \pi (n-1) (k-1) / N}$ such that overall, $ifft(fft(x)) = fft(ifft(x)) = x$